# Проблема подключение Tron Smart Contract к кошельку Scatter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blockchain

Подключаю Smart Contract в сети Tron к кошельку Scatter. При вызове метода контракта идет бесконечный запрос. Скорее всего проблема в том, что не появляется модальное окно Scatter для подтверждения транзакции. Потому что если делать обычную транзакцию, все работает.

```
await contract.buyTickets(amount, partner).send({
          shouldPollResponse: true,
          callValue: window.tronWeb.toSun(amount),
        })
          .then(() => {
            setLoad(false);
            showAlert(`${amount} ${token} transact from ${auth.wallet}`, 'success');
          })
          .catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
            setLoad(false);
            showAlert(`Transaction error! PLease, try again latter!`, 'error')
          });
```

В метод контракта передается количество `amount` изначально равное 1, `partner` id партнера.
Контракт создаю через функцию

```
async function getContract(tron) {
    return await tron.contract().at(contractAddress);
  }
```

`tron` - это объект сети TronWeb создаю через

```
ScatterJS.trx(network, tron)
```

Все работает правильно до транзакции.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен. Нужно было подключать контракт с помощью адреса и abi. Ошибка была в асинхронных запросах.
Может кому поможет.